# showing and hiding div on mouse over n mouse out in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

i have 3 divs with id 1,2,3 , all i want is to show div with id 2 when mouse over on div with id 1 and show div 1 when mouse out event on div 2. and along with that div 3 appears when a button is clicked on div 2 with id btn n if we mouse out of the div 3 again div 1 appears and and we again mouseover the div 1 div 3 appears. n they must appear at the same place...use javascript  plz...here is simple html code...

```
<div id="1" style="position:absolute; height:200px; width:200px;">
<table width="100%" border="01">
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<div id="2" style="position:absolute; height:200px; width:200px;">
  <table width="100%" border="01">
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="button" id="btn"></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>

<div id="3" style="position:absolute; height:200px; width:200px;">
  <table width="100%" border="01">
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>

    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: have you tried anything so far? Or just looking for a solution without making any effort?

Comment: m trying to achieve something like this ...jst take a look on any glass...http://www.lenskart.com/sunglasses/collections/sports-sunglasses.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something in Pure Javascript:

```
    <script>
        var div_one = document.getElementById("1")
        var div_two = document.getElementById('2');
        var div_three = document.getElementById('3');
        var button = document.getElementById('btn');

        var common_div = 2;

        div_one.onmouseover=function(){
            if(common_div==3)
                div_three.style.display = 'block';
            else
                div_two.style.display = 'block';
            div_one.style.display = 'none';
        };

        div_two.onmouseout=function(){
            div_one.style.display = 'block';
            div_two.style.display = 'none';
        };

        div_three.onmouseout=function(){
            common_div = 3;
            div_one.style.display = 'block';
            div_two.style.display = 'none';
            div_three.style.display = 'none';
        };

        button.onclick = function(){
            div_three.style.display = 'block';
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: its not working for the divs overlapping each other...m trying to achieve something like this.. just check on any glass  http://www.lenskart.com/sunglasses/collections/sports-sunglasses.html

Comment: In lenskart, if you may have noticed the all 3 divs of an item is inside a container. No need to specify a position.

Comment: `<div class="container">  
<div class="wrapper1"><!-- contains the default content--></div>  
<div class="wrapper2">  
  <div class="div3"></div>  
  <div class="div2"></div>  
</div>  
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $( "#div2" ).mouseover(function() {
      $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div2").show();
    });
```

More Info: [**LINK**](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/)

**EDIT:** additional info [**LINK2**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_mouseover_mouseout)

Comment: n what if i hav to use dynamic ids of div

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jquery first.
Then try

```
 $('#div1').mouseover(function() {
    $('#div1').style.display='none';
    $('#div2').style.display='block';
 });
 $('#div2').mouseout(function() {
    $('#div1').style.display='block';
 });
 $('#btn').onclick(function() {
    $('#div3').style.display='block';
 });
```

I hope, this works ;)
You could also try to use

```
 $('#div1').style.visibility='hidden';
```

instead of

```
 $('#div1').style.display='none';
```